# Failed building wheel for pyaudio in window

Tags: python, pyaudio

```
import pyaudio

def tackCommand():

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listning......")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. I've taken the liberty to format your code sample, but you'll still want to improve your question. As it is, we can only see a code snippet, with no clear description of what supposedly is going wrong, what you expect to happen, etc. Please have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: yeah me too microsoft studio c++ required

Comment: Hello White Devil, Would you be able to copy paste your error message please? I believe pyaudio requires few support libraries to be installed and few of them cannot be installed with pip. Follow the [instructions here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/).

Comment: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio       it contains precompiled wheel

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```